# c# declare subclass as type superclass

Tags: c#, inheritance

I can't seem to find a satisfactory answer to this inheritance question. Why do you declare a subtype like this sometimes:

```
Shape myCircle = new Circle();
```

and this other times?

```
Circle myShape = new Circle();
```

Where Circle is a **child/sub-class** of `Shape` .....

There doesn't seem to be consistency across the OO books I've been reading and an explanation I can get my head around. People have shown me examples of a Shapes class being instantiated for circles, squares, etc... But I don't understand when you use the 1st declaration and the second.

Answer (score 7):

It is often desirable to treat objects of concrete class [polymorphically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) to avoid creating dependencies on specific types where you can avoid them. For example, if you are creating a `Circle` with the intention of drawing it, and `Draw()` is a method of a `Shape`, then it is better to declare `myCircle` as a shape, in case you decide to replace it with a square later on.

On the other hand, if your intention is to do something specific to `Circle`, say, to set its radius, then you need to declare `myCircle` as `Circle`, because `SetRadius()` may not be available on the `Shape`.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you have a list of shapes, and you don't particularly care what kind of shapes they are because what you need to do with that list is general to all shapes (ie draw), you would want to add them to the list like this

```
List<Shape> shapeList = new List<Shape>();
shapeList.Add(new Circle());
shapeList.Add(new Rectangle());
foreach (Shape shape in shapeList)
{
    shape.Draw();
}
```

This way you can access the general methods of shapes on objects that are actually different types but share a common parent.  Then if you want to do something specific to circles you can use the same list like this.

```
foreach (Shape shape in shapeList)
{
    if (!(shape is Circle)) continue;
    Circle circle = shape as Circle;
    circle.Radius = 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @dasblinkenlight 's answer, you would use the first declaration, instead of the second one, because you want to restrict the behaviour of `myCircle` object to the `Circle`'s members.

That's because `Circle` is a subclass of `Shape`, and it would mean that all the members of `Shape` will be inherited by `Circle`, and, in some cases, because you're using C# (and overriding the members isn't always the rule, like in Java), overridden.

You cannot do the opposite:

```
Circle myCircle = new Shape();
```

The reason is described [here](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Can_a_super_class_varialble_can_reference_a_subclass_object_in_java).

Otherwise, if you're using the second declaration, `myCircle` will be a `Circle` object, using the members and the methods available of `Circle`.